# Mailchimp API - send update notification for existing subscribers

Tags: mailchimp-api-v3.0

I have the following workflow using the Mailchimp API:

1. User is signing up on a form and uses the button "I want to opt in for the newsletter"
2. The User is posted to the Mailchimp API with status `pending` and receives a double-opt-in email
3. The User clicks on the confirm button and his status is changing to ```subscribed``

Now there is a chance, the user is coming back to another form in my app, but clicks again on the button "I want to opt in for the newsletter"

Now I have two possibilities:

1. My script is checking weather the user already exists on the list, in this case -> ignore and do nothing
2. My script triggers a Mailchimp "Update Details" Mailing which asks the user to update its details

1st case is easily doable with the Mailchimp API.
2nd case I know is possible via Mailchimp Widgets but I have not found anything in the API docu to trigger this update mailing.

I know about the different status: https://developer.mailchimp.com/documentation/mailchimp/guides/manage-subscribers-with-the-mailchimp-api/ but nothing is reflecting this particular case ("User already subscribed").

I'd like to know how I can do that and how I can trigger an "update details" mailing via the API.

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know and from what it sounds like you've seen as well there isn't a pre-built option or endpoint in place to trigger MC's update profile email.

But because this version of their email is essentially just a link to the existing subscribers list profile, one of the following workarounds might be worth a shot.

1) Use their API automation workflow option to send existing subscribers an email with their update profile link using the merge tag:

- `*|UPDATE_PROFILE|*`
- Doc on that Automation API endpoint: https://developer.mailchimp.com/documentation/mailchimp/reference/automations/emails/queue/
- Doc on update profile: http://kb.mailchimp.com/campaigns/design/add-an-update-profile-link

Alternatively if you'd like to try and serve subscribers their profile link right on your form after your script check in #2 that to could be done after retrieving:

- the subscribers `unique_email_id`
- From: https://developer.mailchimp.com/documentation/mailchimp/reference/lists/members/#read-get_lists_list_id_members_subscriber_hash

and appending that hashed id to end of the lists specific Update profile URL as the value for `e=`

Which would lead them to their existing pre-filled update profile form:

E.g: `http://mailchimp.{USX}.list-manage.com/profile?u=839fhdd4dd38abf344924fa&id=f29uundc48d&e={unique_email_id}`

Your list specific URL sans the e= value can be obtained from using the update profile merge tag in their Campaign builder and using preview or sending yourself a test email.

Comment: This is very helpful. I managed to create a custom update profile link outside of MailChimp thanks to these suggestions! Thank you!